# How to disable Mysite feature from sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, central-administration, farm-admin

Our public facing website has developed on sharepoint 2013, we have mysite feature enabled and around 40,000 user profiles are their in Mysite.

We now don't want any user to be able to browse Mysite option, for this purpose we have deleted the link button for my sites from home page but some users had  saved their link so they are still able to view their site.

May I please know how to disable it permanently??

What I did is

Went to CA>Manage Web Application>User Profile Service Application>SetUp Mysites>Disable all the features >Saved

Still we are able to get mysite.

Comment: what is requirement, you dont want to create new one or you want to disable exisitng mysites as well?

Comment: I want so disable existing mysites sir. but there is no option to go in mysite site settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your information, this is not easy due to single web application with mixing of mysite and other sites.Couple of things you can try.

- Lock all mysites in that web application as No access. No body can access mysite after this.

  > $sites = get-spsite -WebApplication $webapp -Limit All
  >
  > ```
  > foreach($site in $sites)
  >
  > {
  >     if($site -like "*/mysite/*") 
  >     {
  >         Set-SPSite -Identity $site -LockState "NoAccess"
  >
  >         Write-Host "site status" $site.WriteLocked
  >     }
  > }
  > ```

Another option is hide the option from the user( i am not sure if that work).

- Go to Central Administration > Application Management > Manage
  service applications > User profile service application
- From the ribbon, Click “Manage User Permissions” under People.
- On this page remove both group then no body will access the person page

Check this link for more info. http://howtosharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/11/hide-disable-my-site-my-profile-and.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion sir, 
second approach is not working.

First approach I tried individually to make one user mysite to no access but still he is able to view 

sites/mysites/Pages/Grades.aspx

This pages, which we actually dont want to show.

Comment: Alhamdulillah the problem has been resolved.

I just went to the Central Administration>Configure Quotas and locks>Selected MySite url in the web application>Made it to NoAccess>Saved

Now it's working as we wanted before,

Dear Waqas sir thank you so much for your suggestion.

Comment: The lockstate was something new to me! Nice. :)

Comment: Yeah for me too :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply open the SharePoint 2013 Management Shell and run the following command:

```
Disable-SPFeature 'MySite'
```

Please note that this is a Farm feature, not a Site Collection feature. Be sure you are targeting the right Farm if you have multiple ones. If you make a mistake, you can always re-enable it using:

```
Enable-SPFeature 'MySite'
```

Answer (score 1):

As all the sites are still available, you should be able to add a security group with all your users / the SharePoint group called "Everyone" to your MySite webapplication and give them the permission "Deny All - Has no access."

While they will only get an access denied message while trying to browse their site, you should set up a redirection in IIS to redirect your users somewhere else explaining why MySite is disabled.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response,

Can u please tell me from where to create this group it's actually confusing me???

Comment: The group above is created by SharePoint. You could create a security group in your AD and add here as well.

Comment: but that reflects even in public facing site I guess.

Comment: That's a good point, but do you have your mysites as a separate web application per Microsofts recommendation? Or do you share a webapplication for content and mysites?

Comment: Unfortunately that is the problem we have, if we would have separate web application then at least we would have detached the database.

Yes it is available in same web application where our public facing website is available.

Comment: Then i think that you will need to move the mysites to another content database. How was the sites created? Self-service site creation? I think that the best for you now would be to read up on how to set up mysites and try to backtrack do disable everything related to mysites. Do you need to save the sites already created?

Comment: Thank you so much for your advices, I will definitely try it

Yes we need to have all the existing sites, but we dont want to display those sites to any user.

Comment: I'm thinking that a IIS rule should do it, but as a quick fix until you come up with something else, like redirect every attempt to access http://server/sites/mysites/*

Comment: I TRIED,but unable to find an option to redirect mysites to any page.

I mean I have not found where to mention this, we have one redirect option in our web application,but I guess when user enters the web application url it will redirect to that particular url, but how to enter sites/mysites then it should redirect to sites/pagenotfound.aspx

I'm really in need of this, it's also enough for us as of now.

Comment: Yeah I have fond the way to get the url rewrite rule.

I just downloaded url rewrite and configured.

Now trying to redirect mysite pages

Comment: @Asrar ah yes the URL rewrite module is great, just remember that updating the IIS config file (basically what the module does) requires an IIS reset for the changes to take place.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your suggesions.

Actually I have given NoAccess to mysite so it's working now as we needed.

Comment: @Asrar Glad that you solved it. :)

Answer (score 0):

The below MySite feature in Farm level to prevent the redirection in Created/Modified by in list/libraryand user name links in list/library/user/groups/share but the redirection from Site Actions (About Me) should be handled using JQuery/JavaScript.

Disable-SPFeature -Id 69cc9662-d373-47fc-9449-f18d11ff732c

More details check [this blog](http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2020/03/disable-redirection-from-user-details.html)!